# console.dir(event.target.value) is empty string, but console.dir(event) shows a "full string" for the value property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, onpaste

I have an input element with an onPaste event handler. When I paste a string of text (eg "A string I pasted") into the input the `event` gives me an empty string "" value:

```html
<input onPaste={handleOnPaste} placeholder="paste image or url here"></input>
```

```js
    function handleOnPaste(e) {
        const stringValue = e.target.value;
        console.log({ stringValue }); // logs ""
        console.dir({target: e.target}) // logs "A string I pasted". See image below
        console.dir({value: e.target.value}) // logs ""
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

1. Why does `console.dir(e.target)` provide an object with a different `value` than `console.dir(e.target.value)`.
2. How do I access the value that contains a string in my javascript?

Comment: `console.dir(e.target)` is printing stale data  (call by reference) and `console.dir(e.target.value)` is printing actual data that was present at that moment of compiling..

Comment: But the ```e.target``` value is a more up to date value than the ```e.target.value```. So it would be correct to say that the latter is the stale data I think? Do you know if it's possible to access the ```e.target``` (more up to date) value with javascript, or is it limited to the developer tools console?